# MySQL procedure show a "select" statement twice

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have lots of stored procedures doing a bunch of alter, create etc... and I want to see on each procedure which one are being executed.

```
DELIMITER |

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test1|

CREATE PROCEDURE test1()
    BEGIN
        IF /*select ...  */ THEN
            BEGIN
                SELECT "hello world";
            END;
        END IF;
END|

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test2|

CREATE PROCEDURE test2()
    BEGIN
        IF /*select ...  */ THEN
            BEGIN
                SELECT "hello world 2";
            END;
        END IF;
END|

DELIMITER ;
CALL test1();
CALL test2();
```

then i call it:

```
cat proc.sql | mysql -uroot -p mydb
```

output:

```
hello world
hello world
hello world 2
hello world 2

root@localhost:test> select version();
+-------------------------+
| version()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
```

why it shows twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column name and value is displayed.

```sql
mysql> CALL test1();
+-------------+
| hello world | <- Column name
+-------------+
| hello world | <- Value
+-------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

If you assign an alias to your column:

```sql
...
SELECT "hello world" `column_name`;
...
```

output:

```
column_name
hello world
```

**UPDATE**

Use:

```
$ cat proc.sql | mysql -uroot -p -N mydb
```

output:

```
hello world
hello world 2
```

See: [--skip-column-names, -N](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_skip-column-names)